# What do you call a collection of user answers in a survey?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine that you are answering the following survey:

```
Q1: What is your name?
A1: ..................

Q2: What are you doing?
A2: ...................
```

After you fill in the gaps (as a user):

```
Q1: What is your name?
A1: Ali.

Q2: What are you doing?
A2: Asking a question.
```

As we already know the questions and the structure of the survey we can omit them and we will have the following structure:

```
Q1 answer: Ali.
Q2 answer: Asking a question.
```

What would you call the new structure in the context of programming? I mean, the questions' answers of a specific user.
I prefer to have a single word to represent that (two words is acceptable, but they should be small).

I considered some combinations like: "Survey answers", "User answers", "User responses", and "Respondent data", but non of them is satisfying.

Comment: What do you find unsatisfying about the word combinations that you've already considered?

Comment: Survey results would be too simple?

Comment: The noun *survey* can be used for a completed survey. Or *answer sheet*. *Response* also seems fine, although you probably want to differentiate the completed survey from the response to a single question. It should be noted that asking what to call your variable/database field/etc is off topic.

Comment: Fill the blanks, not the gaps. :)

Comment: @Lambie thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @KillingTime I hoped to find a single word to represent it, but it looks like I will use two words :(

Comment: @YosefBaskin it is simple, but it is two words :(

Comment: @StuartF sorry if I'm asking something un-related, but I searched a lot and I didn't find anything :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**raw (survey) data / primary (survey) data**

> **Raw data**, also known as **primary data**, are data (e.g., numbers,
> instrument readings, figures, etc.) collected from a source. In the
> context of examinations, the raw data might be described as a raw
> score (after test scores). [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_data)

> Part of the survey process centers on **raw data** that are collected
> from respondents and converted into data sets. The entire conversion
> process needs data management. in general, good software packages need
> to deal with the data and ... [Paul Lavrakas; *Encyclopedia of Survey
> Research Methods*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopedia_of_Survey_Research_Methods/2sr0CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Part%20of%20the%20survey%20process%20centers%20on%20raw%20data%20that%22) (2008)

> Capturing and Processing Survey Data
>
> There are several ways of entering **raw data** into a format
> suitable for data processing. [Donald Treadwell; *Introducing
> Communication Research*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introducing_Communication_Research/1giD1aMTjEkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=user%20survey%20%22raw%20data%22%20is%20formatted&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

Comment: I liked the usage of word "raw", I will accept this answer and use it. I'm still not sure, should I use "RawSurveyData" or "RawResponses". I will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The data collected from survey questions are **survey responses**:

> Get your **survey responses** rolling in. We’ll show how to get your survey in front of your respondents.

[Survey Monkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/tour/responsecollection/)

[Note: I chose this site because it is well known. However, I would have put a "you" in after the verb show.]

Comment: The fact that Survey Monkey using "survey responses" in their website is interesting, I didn't think about searching in their website. But the question is what they are naming this field internally? It could be survey responses, and it could be something else.